# Could a “Kerl” be female?

Tags: gender, meaning

Some translations for *Kerl* are *fellow*, *bloke*, *guy*, *chap* and *dude*. Most of them are (somewhat) gender-neutral. What about *Kerl*?

Comment: For 'answers' and commentary on the English side, see [What is a feminine version of guys?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19074/what-is-a-feminine-version-of-guys) and [What is a feminine version of dude?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19093/what-is-a-feminine-version-of-dude). My synopsis: the English words in your list above are possible to use with females, but are not 'somewhat' gender-neutral, they are words primarily used for masculine situations. But, from the commentary below it seems that 'guy' has more instances than 'Kerl' where it can be used with women.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From Duden:

> (durch bestimmte [positive Charakter]eigenschaften charakterisierter) Mensch
>
> Beispiele
>
> - ein patenter Kerl
> - sie ist ein feiner, netter, prächtiger, guter Kerl
> - ein lieber, goldiger, tapferer Kerl (Junge)

It is mostly used for male persons, but may be used for women as well. Be careful though, because in addition to this rather neutral meaning, it also has the meaning of *man*, which you can't say to a woman obviously, unless you want to insult her or want to explicitly express that she's (in some regards) like a man or a good *Kumpel*, like *jemand mit dem man Pferde stehlen kann*.

Another meaning of *Kerl* is *Liebhaber* (lover).

---

Note that the definition from Duden is important: *Kerl* is used for females in the sense of "(durch bestimmte [positive Charakter]eigenschaften charakterisierter) Mensch" - in the sense of *Mann*, *Liebhaber* or *Prachtexemplar*, it is not, at least not without causing offense. From the Grimm:

> b) einige verbindungen, wie *guter kerl*, *dummer kerl*, *närrischer kerl*, sind so feste eigene begriffe geworden, dasz sie mit vergessen des geschlechts darin auch von frauen, mädchen, kindern, allerlei persönlichen wesen gesagt werden; frauen nennen sich wol selbst so in vertraulicher rede, im selbstgespräch. so sagen sie ja auch *man* von sich, und *unser einer*.

For these reasons, a woman may not be a *Kerl*, but she may be a *netter Kerl*. However, the positive adjective is sometimes omitted, even though the gender-neutral meaning is intended. Of course, it may be easier to avoid offense by *just not using the word*. But that would be too easy, wouldn't it? ;)

Comment: Interesting. I never heard of *Kerl* being used for females.

Comment: Kerl is nerver used for females. May be correct, but more than uncommon.

Comment: @infinitesimalLeanne: Not true. I have heard and read it several times for females. And I don't mean examples in dictionaries. It is then typically used with adjectives, like in the Duden examples, though. See [the Grimm](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=11,570,13).

Comment: "Typ" is another word that denotes a man when used without an adjective, while "Sie ist ein toller Typ" is common.

Comment: @Stefan Walter: What about "Sie ist nicht mein Typ"? :) I get your point though, +1 for that ;)

Comment: Maybe regional :) I've asked a few friends of mine, no one has ever used or heard it. So we can say: regional and ancient

Comment: It's neither, nor. It just has two meanings. One has to be accompanied by an adjective, since it is a colloquial expression describing someone's character, the other is the actual translation for chap, dude, bloke etc. It is not really uncommon to use it both ways in any part of germany.

Comment: AFAIK, all the usages for a female, being a Kerl, try to express that she has attributes like a man, like in 'zum Pferde stehlen'. Therefore I partly agree with @infinitesimalLeanne.

Comment: My example with stealing horses explicitly uses the meaning of "man", and I'd agree for this meaning. The other meaning cannot be used for someone to steal horses with, but for any person (or thing or animal, for that matter, see the Grimm) without implying that they're like men. Both Duden and the Grimm state that this meaning exists in addition to the "man" meaning. The two meanings are distinct, as @Semyazas explained. Of course, anything can be misunderstood. "Information entsteht beim Empfänger". Note that I was not implying that stealing horses is a good thing, independent of gender.

Comment: @user unknown you are completely right. If you want to express something like "Mannsweib" than it's possible to say: "Sie ist wie ein Kerl" or something like this.

Comment: @infinitesimalLeanne: Excuse me, talking german. Ein `Mannsweib` ist eine Person, die als Ganzes vom Sprecher mannähnlich wahrgenommen wird, während ein `feiner Kerl` durchaus eine zierliche, feminine Gestalt sein kann, der aber besondere Fairness, oder männliche Verhaltensattribute zugeordnet werden, womit ich nicht sagen will, dass nur oder vorwiegend Männer fair, treu, aufrichtig oder verläßlich wären. Aber die Attribute von Kameradschaft, wie man sie unter Männern vermutet sind hier gemeint, und es wird von sexuellen Reizen abgesehen. ...

Comment: Intersexuelle Beziehungseigenschaften werden mit 'Kerl' bewußt ausgeblendet. Beispielsweise würde Treue zw. Frau und Mann gleich als auf eine Liebschaft bezogen interpretiert, obwohl es auch Treue zwischen heterosexuellen Frauen oder Männern gibt. Umgekehrt wird aber nicht gesagt, dass die Person, die ein feiner Kerl sei, asexuell ist - nur, dass eine Eigenschaft nicht in dem Kontext betrachtet wird.

Comment: Wouldn't have believed a legal use of Kerl for females if it weren't for the Duden. FWIW, I've never used, seen or heard such a use. (native speaker, eastern Germany)

Answer (score 8):

As OregonGhost mentioned in a comment, the key to this is in the adjectives. Without adjectives, "Kerl" can only be applied to males and basically means "guy", and can but need not have negative connotations, as in "Was ist *das* denn für ein Kerl?". The negative use is relatively common, whereas the neutral use synonymous with "man" is obsolescent except in certain dialects. With positive adjectives, however, as in the Duden entry OregonGhost cites, "Kerl" can also be applied to females, though this is not very common.

Comment: I think you're right. In the meantime I added more to my answer, including a quote from the Grimm, which mentions that certain set expressions are used for women, though some of the examples are with *negative* adjectives. It may not be very common today, but it is more common than *never* ;) Welcome to the site, by the way :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'negative use'?

Answer (score 4):

I think, most women would be outright offended to be referred to as a "Kerl".

Comment: Correct. I have never heard anybody using "Kerl" to address a woman.

Comment: +1 I think that's an important aspect. It is still possible (on the verge of becoming obsolete) *among men* to say "Sie ist ein Pfundskerl." *about* a woman - but none of these men would say it *to* her (except when she's proud of and cultivating a certain tomboyishness). NOTE: "Pfundskerl" does *not* refer to the person's weight - it means "great guy" :)